# Spring Validator - show errors using <form:errors

Tags: java, spring, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working in a spring mvc web app where i am trying to validate an db object `person` using Spring's Validator and trying to show the result of validator in JSP form as `form:errors path=""`.
I have server side method in a controller as :

```
@RequestMapping( value="/find", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public ModelAndView search(@ModelAttribute("Person") Person p,BindingResult result){

     Person person2 = personDao.get( p.getId() );
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("templates/person");

     PersonValidator personValidator = new PersonValidator();
     personValidator.validate(person2, result);
     mav.addObject("person",person2);
     mav.addObject("errors",result.getFieldErrors());

     return mav;
}
```

I have JSP code as :

```
<form:form commandName="person" >
    <form:input path="personEmail" /> 
    <form:errors path="personEmail"  element="div" />
</form:form>
```

It works if I explicitly put the error message `${errors.personEmail }`

But ,

```
<form:errors path="personEmail"  element="div" />
```

does not work.

Could you please suggest me what's wrong here?

Comment: What does `PersonValidator` do?

Comment: Its a simple Spring Validator. Its implementation looks like `public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) { `

Comment: The important part is the `validate` method body.  Are you calling `result.rejectValue` in the validate method?  Also try changing @ModelAttribute to `person` (lower-case p)

Comment: Yes, I am calling rejectIfEmpty as  - `public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
 ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, field, "required","required");
}`. I also tried using `person` instead of `p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following changes and it is solved now. :D

```
@RequestMapping( value="/find", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String search(@ModelAttribute("Person") Person p,BindingResult result,ModelMap model){

         Person person2 = personDao.get( p.getId() );
         PersonValidator personValidator = new PersonValidator();
         Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(person2, "person");
         personValidator.validate(person2, errors);
         model.addAttribute("person",person2);
         model.addAttribute("errors",errors);

         return "templates/person";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try to narrow variable names.

You have got @Model Attribute("Person") where the command is named Person than in your jsp you  have  person and in   personValidator.validate(person, result); you have person . 
You should validate the same object which is preceding BindingResult => Person p or you have to create binding result for particular object explicitly like this

```
BindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(person,"person");
validate(Person person, Errors errors);
```